# Multiple dots on numeric Edittext

Tags: android

I have an EditText which type is android:inputType="numberDecimal" with a watcher on which I change the output.
When the number is greater than 1000 the output is 1.000 or 2.000.

The problem is that my text watcher won't react to the "." key of the softkeyboard when the entered input has already a "."

Any ideas on how to get it to react the this event in this case ?

Comment: Why would you want to enter more than one "." character?

Comment: @LukeWaggoner when the number is < than 1000 as the dot is pressed I change it to a "," symbol, so "."is for "thousands" separation and "," for decimals.

Comment: Why are you using "," for decimals and "." for thousands? Special currency or number format from another country?

Comment: Yes, there are other cultures existing outside the US.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it like so:

```
editText.setKeyListener( new SomeClassDigitsKeyListener( false, true ) );
```

SomeClassDigitsKeyListener:

```
@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                           Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
    CharSequence out = super.filter(source, start, end, dest, dstart, dend);

    if (".".equals(source)) {
        return ",";
    }
    else {
        return out;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

Use `afterTextChange()` in your textwatcher...

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable view) {
    String s = null;
    try {
        s = String.format("%.d", Long.parseLong(view.toString()));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately afterTextChanged is not being called (neither are onBefore and onText), this is basically the problem.